# Any good way of checking if a json object is a subset of another one in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

By a is a json subset of b, I mean

- For object, b has all the key-value pairs as in a.
- For array, b has the same size as a, the order doesn't matter though

  ```
  {"one":1}.should be_subset_json({"one":1,"two":2})
  [{"one":1}].should_NOT be_subset_json([{"one":1},{"two":2}])
  [{"two":2},{"one":1}].should be_subset_json([{"one":1},{"two":2}])
  [{"id":1},{"id":2}].should be_subset_json([{"id":2, "name":"b"},{"id":1,"name":"a"}])
  ```

Comment: JSON? Or regular ruby arrays and hashes?

Comment: Ah, I was using JSON.parse for the example.

Answer (score 3):

Just implementing your spec there seems to work.

```
require 'json'

def diff_structure(a, b)
  case a
  when Array
    a.map(&:hash).sort == b.map(&:hash).sort
  when Hash
    a.all? {|k, v| diff_structure(v, b[k]) }
  else
    a == b
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_subset_json do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    diff_structure JSON.parse(actual), JSON.parse(expected)
  end
end

describe "Data structure subsets" do
  specify { '{"one":1}'.should be_subset_json('{"one":1,"two":2}') }
  specify { '[{"one":1}]'.should_not be_subset_json('[{"one":1},{"two":2}]') }
  specify { '[{"two":2},{"one":1}]'.should be_subset_json('[{"one":1},{"two":2}]') }
  specify { '{"a":{"one":1}}'.should be_subset_json('{"a":{"one":1,"two":2}}') }
end

# Data structure subsets
#   should be subset json "{\"one\":1,\"two\":2}"
#   should not be subset json "[{\"one\":1},{\"two\":2}]"
#   should be subset json "[{\"one\":1},{\"two\":2}]"
#   should be subset json "{\"a\":{\"one\":1,\"two\":2}}"
# Finished in 0.00172 seconds
# 4 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: why this line `a.map(&:hash).sort == b.map(&:hash).sort` ?

Comment: Because `Hash` isn't necessarily comparable, but we can test for equality in this case by (ab)using `Object#hash`. Try `[{two: 2}, {one: 1}].sort`.

Comment: I mean OP said to check the size (***For array, b has the same size as a, the order doesn't matter though***),not the content.. Thus I asked why you wrote such an extra logic?

Comment: If he truly just wants to test size, then yes, it's redundant. It would seem silly for `[1]` to be a subset of `["argleblargle"]` though.